# What are the equilibria?

Tags: calculus

I have the following equations:

$\frac{du(t)}{dt}=-au^2(t)+(a-1)u(t)$

$\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=av^2(t)-(a-1)v(t)$

I have to find equilibrium points for these equations. I figured I should look for the points where $\frac{du(t)}{dt}=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=0$, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the derivatives to zero, you get two factorable quadratic equations, which have the solutions

$$u(t)=0\quad\text{or}\quad u(t)=\frac{a-1}a$$

and

$$v(t)=0\quad\text{or}\quad v(t)=\frac{a-1}a$$

This gives four equilibrium points, unless $a=0$ or $a=1$.

Comment: Or $u=0$, $v=0$.

Comment: @nullUser: I seem to have added those possibilities to my answer shortly before you finished your comment. But thanks for the catch.